# Why remove systemd random seed in read-only filesystems?

Tags: raspbian, systemd, systemd-startup

I'm following [this excellent tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/make-your-raspberry-pi-file-system-read-only-raspbian-buster-c558694de79).

In it, he guides through creating a read-only filesystem for raspberry pis.

One of the steps is to remove the systemd/random-seed

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/systemd/random-seed
$ sudo ln -s /tmp/random-seed /var/lib/systemd/random-seed
```

And  edit the systemd random seed loader to load a blank file on startup

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
#### New line here:
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "" >/tmp/random-seed
#### End new line  ^^
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed load
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed save
TimeoutSec=30s
```

## My question

Why is it required to do that? What security implications might it have with or without removing that?

Comment: I thought `the file is immediately updated with a new seed` makes it obvious - you can't update a file on a read-only filesystem

Comment: Yes, probably. That's also why it makes sense to link it to /tmp. I wonder if this is an awful thing to do for other reasons / maybe I should create the seed  from something other than ""

Answer (score 2):

OK, after some discussion and reading I think I have an answer. It's not as good as I had hoped.

## Why remove random-seed?

Well, on shutdown, systemd will attempt to write the file.

[see man systemd](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-random-seed.8.html)

> systemd-random-seed.service is a service that loads an on-disk random seed into the kernel entropy pool during boot and saves it at shutdown.

and

> When loading the random seed from disk, the file is immediately updated with a new seed retrieved from the kernel, in order to ensure no two boots operate with the same random seed.

Presumably, we save the systemd from writing to a read-only file.

**I have verified that the pi boots and reboots fine with or without pointing the random-seed file to /tmp, so it might be a wash.**

## What are the implications of removing random-seed?

And also from the [link in the man page](https://systemd.io/RANDOM_SEEDS/)

> The systemd-random-seed.service system service will load a random seed from /var/lib/systemd/random-seed into the kernel entropy pool. By default it does not credit entropy for it though, since the seed is — more often than not — not reset when ‘golden’ master images of an OS are created, and thus replicated into every installation.

Further [this discussion from github/systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4271)

> I am particularly concerned with systems that use "golden master" images, that contain the a random seed and are duplicated many times. In this case i figure the entropy of the random seed should be considered zero, but I doubt we could ever distinguish this case from the normal, clean case.

Which implies (to me), that it's fairly common to have a boring random-seed duplicated across images. This implies that it might be fine to either

- Create a random-seed for your "master" pi image that is duplicated across your  various devices (seems standard practice)
- Create a blank random-seed for all of them (as suggested by the tutorial)
- Create a random-seed file  for *each* new pi image that is frozen read-only (for example by leaving the file system r/w and rebooting once then leaving it read-only from then on)
- leave it blank as suggested in the tutorial.

I've posted a follow-up question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650412/22520) to see if others can help.